# For loop only iterating last element in list

Tags: python, loops

```
list =[]
number = int(input("how many names do you want in a list: "))
for i in range(0,number):    
    string_list = (input("enter desired names:"))
    list.append(string_list)

all_freq = {}
for i in string_list:
    if i in all_freq: 
        all_freq[i] += 1
    else: 
        all_freq[i] = 1
print(list)
print ("Count of all characters in names is :\n "
                                        +  str(all_freq))
```

Comment: Hello. Why do you need this to do? Why do you not used `len()` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len And if you need last elemnt only in the list variable, there is possible to use the last index: `var[-1]` . Or write exactly what you need, because unfortunately it is not obvious from your inquiry.

Comment: This is quite odd, can you explain what you're trying to do? Also, naming a variable `list` is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
list =[]
number = int(input("how many names do you want in a list: "))
for i in range(0,number):    
    string_list = (input("enter desired names:"))
    list.append(string_list)

all_freq = {}
for name in list:
    for c in name:
        if c in all_freq: 
            all_freq[c] += 1
        else: 
            all_freq[c] = 1

print ("Count of all characters in names is :\n "
                                        +  str(all_freq))
```

Comment: Well, if it is not a condition for the input from the user to include the number of items in the list variable, then it is foolish to ask first about the number of names for the list. It doesn't have to be there at all. The `.append` method adds items to the list variable, regardless of whether or not it is already there. So the query on the total number of names in the resulting list variable is ineffective. :-/

Comment: @s3no right, name_list = [for name in input().split()] is more better. But I left it because I don't know what this code written for. There may be a fixed input.

Comment: @kwd9502 No, I meant something else. There is no need to determine how much the user wants to enter the number of names (items per list). Normally, the user can enter names and exit by entering a blank character (pressing the ENTER key). Then the number of items can be determined from the object (list type variable) simply with the help of `len(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want the count of every character of all names combine.

You can get the unique characters using set(), and count them using str.count()

```py
    string_list = ""
    number = int(input("how many names do you want in a list: "))
    for i in range(number):
        string_list += input("enter desired name:")
    unique_chars = set(string_list)  # getting all unique characters 
    all_freq = {}
    for i in unique_chars:
        all_freq[i] = string_list.count(i)  # returns the count of the character

    print("Count of all characters in names is :\n "
          + str(all_freq))
```